# What is a good way to manage a large number of configurations in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm working on a C++ project under Netbeans that consists of many classes used to create a number of main programs (here: simulation systems). I have a large number of those simulation systems plus test programs, thus I end up with a lot of main programs associated to my project. Generally, I just want to build one of those main programs, so I created a configuration for each of them. The number of configurations now grows and grows and becomes inconvenient. One reason I find it inconvenient, is that many configuration names have the same beginnings and become indistinguishable in the configuration pop down menu.

Is there any tool or plugin allowing a more efficient management of configurations?

Is there a different approach to my task of building many different main programs from one project? It would be wonderful if you could use variables like the name of the currently opened file in the build command of a configuration. In this case I would only need one configuration. (I asked about that in the [Netbeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=36645) but haven't received any answers.)